# Removing special chars from a string

Tags: java, string, jakarta-ee

I use the code to remove all the special chars from a string, but its removing the white spaces also. how can I exclude spaces ?i.e I need to have the white spaces as it is.

```
String alphaAndDigits = keyword.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]+","");
```

Comment: just add them into the regex? `"[^a-zA-Z0-9 \t\n\r]+"` ?

Answer (score 2):

```
String alphaAndDigits = keyword.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z\\d\\s]+","");
```

- `\s` is the matcher for whitespaces `[ \t\n\x0b\r\f]`
- `\d` is the matcher for digits `[0-9]`

`String alphaAndDigits = keyword.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9 \t\n\x0b\r\f]+","");`

would be the same if you prefer that

Answer (score 0):

```
        String alphaAndDigits = "hello&%*..sad**";
        Pattern ptn = Pattern.compile("[^S a-zA-Z0-9]");
        Matcher match = ptn.matcher(alphaAndDigits);
        while (match.find()) {
            String str = match.group();
            alphaAndDigits =alphaAndDigits.replaceAll("\\" + str, "");
        }
        System.out.println(alphaAndDigits);
```